# How do I split a tensor and then concatenate it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

My input data is of the form [None, 2, 100], basically I have a bunch of 2 cell arrays that each contain vectors of size 100. I want to run each vector through a separate input layer, and after that layer concatenate the results into one vector.

My questions are as follows:
Given a tensor of shape [None, 2, 100], how do I transform it to be of size [None, 100]? 
Then, give two tensors, of size [None, 50], how do I concatenate them to be of size [None, 100]?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use numpy-like indexing, `tf.slice` or `tf.unpack`

   ```
   c = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 2, 100])
   d = c[:,0,:]
   e = tf.squeeze(tf.slice(c, [0,1,0], [-1, 1, -1]), squeeze_dims=[1])
   [d, e] = tf.unpack(c, axis=1)
   ```
2. concatenation:

   ```
   a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 50])
   b = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 50])
   tf.concat(1, [a,b]).get_shape()
   TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(100)])
   ```

Comment: Thanks for this. For 1), I don't want to just reshape the tensor. For example, if the tensor is [None, x_1, x_2], I want to separate it into [None, x_1], and [None, x_2].

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
tf.concat(tf.unstack(feature_output), 0)
```